# TransformationError on blob via get_serving_url (app engine)

Tags: google-app-engine, blob

**TransformationError**

This error keeps coming up for a specific image.

There are no problems with other images and I'm wondering what the reason for this exception could be.

From Google:

"Error while attempting to transform the image."

**Update:**

Development server it works fine, only live it fails.

Thanks

Comment: Does the blob exists in blob viewer?

Comment: yes. first thing I did was checked blob viewer and it checks out fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more information I'd say it's either the image is corrupted, or it's in a format that cannot be used with get_serving_url (animate GIF for example).

Comment: the type of image format is JPG (image/jpeg @ 300 * 241) and the image does render in blob viewer

Comment: open an issue on the issue tracker and attach the image.

Comment: After performing some additional tests indeed the images I'm using must be corrupt.

Answer (score 2):

I fought this error forever and incase anyone finds they get the dreaded TransformationError please note that you need to make sure that your app has owner permissions on the files you want to generate a url for

It'll look something like this in your IAM tab:
App Engine app default service account
your-project-name-here@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
In IAM on that member you want to scroll down to Storage and grant "Storage Object Admin" to that user. That is as long as you have your storage bucket under the same project... if not I'm not sure how...

Answer (score 1):

This TransformationError exception seems to show up for permissions errors so it is a bit misleading.

I way getting this error because I had used the *Bucket Policy Only* permissions on a bucket in a different project.

However after **changing this back to *Object Level* permissions** and giving my App Engine app access (from a different project) I was able to perform the App Engine Standard Images operation (google.appengine.api.images.get_serving_url) that I was trying to implement.

Make sure that you set your permissions correctly either in the Console UI or via gsutil like so:

```
gsutil acl ch -u my-project-a@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:OWNER gs://my-project-b
```